# Ruby on Rails hosting with gem "capybara-webkit"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, hosting, openshift, capybara-webkit

I want to deploy a RoR application that uses a gem `capybara-webkit`. Is there any free RoR hosting site capable of using that gem?

Heroku is not capable of using it: [Is it possible to run capybara-webkit (i.e. forked webkit_server) on Heroku Cedar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8983198/is-it-possible-to-run-capybara-webkit-i-e-forked-webkit-server-on-heroku-ceda)

OpenShift is also not capable: https://www.openshift.com/forums/express/error-in-installing-capybara-webkit-gem-while-trying-to-deploy-juvia-rails-app

Is there any other alternative?

Answer (score 0):

I have tired capybara-webkit with digital ocean it works well for me. 
for more information http://blog.55minutes.com/2013/09/running-capybara-webkit-specs-with-jenkins-ci/

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to deploy the app on Heroku (and not run tests with `capybara-webkit` on Heroku), exclude `caybara-webkit` from the installed dependencies on your Heroku app:

`heroku config:add BUNDLE_WITHOUT="development:performance:test"`